# Why is this part repeated three times?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

Here is my code:

```
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;

class motor
{
public:
    motor();
    ~motor();

private:

};

motor::motor()
{
    cout << "I'm the motor of this car." << endl;
}

motor::~motor()
{
    cout << "the motor of this car is removed." << endl;
}

class doors
{
public:
    doors();
    ~doors();

private:

};

doors::doors()
{
    cout << "I'm the doors of this car." << endl;
}

doors::~doors()
{
    cout << "the doors of this car are removed." << endl;
}

class wheels
{
public:
    wheels();
    ~wheels();

private:

};

wheels::wheels()
{
    cout << "I'm the wheels of this car." << endl;
}

wheels::~wheels()
{
    cout << "the wheels of this car are removed." << endl;
}

class car
{
public:
    car(motor m,doors d,wheels w):m(m),d(d),w(w) {
        cout << "This car is assembled" << endl;
    }
    //car() {
    //  cout << "This car is assembled" << endl;
    //}
    ~car() {
        cout << "This car is removed." << endl;
    }

private:
    motor m;doors d;
    wheels w;
};


int main() {
    motor m;
    doors d;
    wheels w;
    car(m, d, w);
    //car();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

**I'm the motor of this car.

I'm the doors of this car.

I'm the wheels of this car.

This car is assembled

the motor of this car is removed.

the doors of this car are removed.

the wheels of this car are removed.

This car is removed.

the wheels of this car are removed.

the doors of this car are removed.

the motor of this car is removed.

the wheels of this car are removed.

the doors of this car are removed.

the motor of this car is removed.**

I am not fully understand the true nature of constructor and destructor in c++, please have someone enlighten me!

Comment: I am a beginner in learning c++.

Comment: This line `car(motor m,doors d,wheels w):m(m),d(d),w(w)` invokes two copy constructors for each of the motor, doors, and wheels. You don't have a custom copy constructor, so it's not printing an "I'm being created" message. Each item is being copied once when passed to the constructor (pass by value), and copied another time when creating the member objects. Consult your teaching staff for more information.

Comment: To help you ask questions in the future: You ask why "this part" is repeated three times, but you never said which part.

Comment: sorry, this part: the motor of this car is removed.

the doors of this car are removed.

the wheels of this car are removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the copy constructor and thus you are facing the problem.

```
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;

class motor
{
public:
    motor();
    motor(const motor& c);
    ~motor();

private:

};

motor::motor()
{
    cout << "A new motor was made" << endl;
}
motor::motor(const motor& c)
{
    cout << "A motor was cloned" << endl;
}

motor::~motor()
{
    cout << "A motor destroyed" << endl;
}


class wheels
{
public:
    wheels();
    wheels(const wheels& c);
    ~wheels();

private:

};

wheels::wheels()
{
    cout << "A new wheel was made" << endl;
}
wheels::wheels(const wheels& c)
{
    cout << "A wheel was cloned" << endl;
}

wheels::~wheels()
{
    cout << "A wheel destroyed" << endl;
}

class car
{
public:
    car(motor m2,wheels w2):m3(m2),w3(w2) {
        cout << "This car is assembled" << endl;
    }
    ~car() {
        cout << "This car is destroyed." << endl;
    }

private:
    motor  m3;
    wheels w3;
};


int main() {
    motor m1;
    wheels w1;
    car(m1, w1);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output

```
A new motor was made
A new wheel was made
A motor was cloned
A wheel was cloned
A motor was cloned
A wheel was cloned
This car is assembled
A wheel destroyed
A motor destroyed
This car is destroyed.
A wheel destroyed
A motor destroyed
A wheel destroyed
A motor destroyed
```

Lets understand the output

- m1 and w1 was created
- w1 is copied to w2 and m1 is copied to m2 ( Here m2,w2 are the argument variables).
- m2 is copied to m3 and w2 is copied to w3 ( The order depends on the order in which m3 and w3 are declared )
- A temporary car object is created
- w2 and m2 are destroyed
- The car object gets destroyed
- m3 and w3 are destroyed
- m1 and w1 are destroyed

Hope that clears your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
motor m;
doors d;
wheels w;
```

Default constructors for motor, doors and wheels are called.

> I'm the motor of this car.
>  I'm the doors of this car.
>  I'm the wheels
> of this car.

```
car(m, d, w);
```

This is doing `:m(m),d(d),w(w)`, which makes 3 copies of parameters (using default copy constructor, for which you don't output anything), and then destroys the copies.

> This car is assembled
>  the motor of this car is removed.
>  the doors of
> this car are removed.
>  the wheels of this car are removed.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Car destructor is executed at the end of the main function. That makes car's private members to be destroyed as well.

> This car is removed.
>  the wheels of this car are removed.
>  the doors of
> this car are removed.
>  the motor of this car is removed.

And so are destructors of motor, doors and wheels.

> the wheels of this car are removed.
> the doors of this car are removed.
> the motor of this car is removed.